# RESTful form, get action design

Tags: forms, get, restful-url, restful-architecture

Following the restful design, an url, where I handle a search query, should look like this:

```
/car/search/Audi
```

and the `/car/search` should display the search form. I think the form should use GET method, but If I set the method to get (`method="get"`), it will redirect to `/car/search/?query=Audi`.

How can I define the form, so It will redirect to `/controller/method/{variable}` ?

Edit.: I am using PHP5.4, Laravel 4

Comment: you could use a `url-rewriting` library to re-write your desire url

Comment: I would rather not, I should set up at least 5-6 form like this, I don't want to rewrite all of them.

Answer (score 0):

this is simpler**

```
Route::get('car', function(){
   echo Form::open(array('url' => 'car/search/', 'method' => 'get'));
   echo Form::text('search');
   echo Form::submit('Click Me!');
   echo Form::close();
});
```

try this it will take your to this url `car/search?search=[entry]`

```
Route::get('car/search', function(){
return Input::get('search');
});
```

another route to catch it! When you use Forms with GEt method it will always give you a querysting parameter. becuase its what get meant to. Unleas you wanna use ajax to send the form manuelly onSubmit! then your could have your route like cars/search/{param}
but in this case it has to be cars/search/?search={params}

Comment: Yeah, but how would you tell the form, to forward the request to this url. 
`<form action="{{ URL::route('route-name') }}" method="get">`
would redirect to car/search?inputname=value

Comment: You edited your answer, still: I am not asking how should I define routes. I would like to know, how can I tell the form, to redirect to the restful pattern.

Comment: Yes if you wait i am just completing my answer :)).

Comment: I can't open the form with the input the user will type in. You say I should `Form::open('route' => array('route.name', $USER's SEARCH INPUT));`

It won't work.

Comment: So, basically, I can't do what I want. Only with ajax, but that way, the url won't change (/car/search containts the form, sends an ajax request to /car/search/xy, but the user's url will be the same, /car/search url and after searching, he/she can't link it to others :().

Comment: basicaly what you need is an input and a button when you click button it will take the input value and redirect your page to /car/search/xy
check out jquery you can easily do it in jquery

Comment: Yeah, true. A button should just redirect to the url. Hmm